# How to show alert message in swiftUI when user enters time below the expected time?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-environment, swiftui-form

I'm building an alarm kinda app and I just want to display a pop up message (alert message) when user enter time below 2 hours, the user should get a message by saying like, "please enter time more than 2 hours of duration".

This is where I stored the alarm value

```
myViewModel.myModel.waketime
```

and I want to display the message when a user click this below image

```
 Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .sheet(isPresented: $showPlayer) {
                            SecondView()
                        }
```

This is another view where the user picks the alarm time

```
 Text("Alarm : ")
  .font(.body)
   Spacer()
   DatePicker("", selection: self.$myViewModel.myModel.waketime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
```

Please help me to solve this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Alert` to show an alert to the user. In order to do this when the user clicks on the `Image`, you'd probably want to wrap it in a `Button`:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var alertShown = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            if true { //here, you can check your condition for whether the alert should get triggered -- like checking `myViewModel.myModel.waketime > x`
                alertShown = true
            }
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .clipShape(Circle())
        }.alert(isPresented: $alertShown) {
            Alert(title: Text("Please enter time more than 2 hours of duration"))
        }
    }
}
```

You may want to add `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())` as a modifier to the `Button` if you don't want it to change your `Image` to the `accentColor` in your project.

**Update in response to comments**:
The general check you'd want to do is:

```
if myViewModel.myModel.waketime.timeIntervalSince1970 - Date().timeIntervalSince1970 < 60 * 60 * 2 {
```

However, be aware that with your current strategy of only showing hours and minutes, this will start to fail at 2 hours before midnight, since the `DatePicker` will default to the current date, making 1 AM, for example, register as *before* the current date/time, not after. So, you'll want to add some additional logic to account for things like that. For example, you could add 24 hours to any time *before* the current date.

Comment: but how will it check with my time? it should retrieve time from "myViewModel.myModel.waketime" and check whether the time is less than or more than 2 hrs. example (if the user sets time at 2:00pm and now the time is 1:00pm, it should give a message and indicate user to enter time duration more than 2hrs)

Comment: Look at the code that I gave -- there's a comment telling you exactly where to do that check. You didn't give any details about what format/time `waketime` is in, so I can't give you the exact code unless you give more details.

Comment: thank you for the reply. could you please check my edited question?

Comment: Updated my response